# Issue in downloading excel in chrome using window.open() method

Tags: javascript, html, excel, google-chrome, url

I have download button. While clicking on this button, it will save an excel file to a share folder and returns the saved path. Using the returned path, I have to download the same file. The file is saved and URL is returned successfully.

I tried below code to download the Excel.

```
window.open("\\\\Folder\\folder\\folder\\filename.xls","_blank");
```

It is working fine in IE, firefox and even in other chrome browser in other system. Unfortunately it is not working in chrome in my machine.
I tried the file path directly in the browser and it quickly downloaded the file. But it is not working through the code.

Chrome version: 46.0.2490.71

Comment: " it is not working in chrome in my machine." What system? What machine?

Comment: @Teemu : Sorry, I ment my computer. Its windows 7.